# Recurring payment with PayPal in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

In my project, I have two types of Payment. One is direct payment with PayPal and second one is recurring payment with PayPal.

I need help only in recurring payment-

**Which hidden fields will be there and what would be their values?**

I want to know how the billing cycle will be continue every month.

> The payment of first month will be different because it will be
>   calculate from the date of joining to end of that month. And remaining
>   payment will be same for every month which will be calculating from
>   database record for whole month.

Comment: I'm currently working on Paypal and to be honest it's horrific, the documentation is severely lacking and the sandbox system has big holes in it - links to 404s, consistency issues, etc. and the overall architecture of Paypal is a mess. I would suggest using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb) as a clean, fast and intelligent alternative,

Comment: I have to do this with PayPal only :(

Comment: This question is a bit broad at the moment - have you tried the documentation? Is the issue that you cannot find the documentation that you need, or does it not make sense? What field values are you passing at the moment, and what response are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/php?env=sandbox

It let's you use fiddle with the code once you have it right copy and paste into your project checkout process.